# Spring boot batch jobs - Exit codes/Return codes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring boot batch application deployed on external Tomcat. The expectation is shell script should call batch jobs and return exit code (0 in case of success and non-zero in case of failure). I’ve implemented below but even the batch is failed, I get 0 return code in shell script. Want to know what is Spring recommended approach to manage these error codes. Please suggest

```
if (jobExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.COMPLETED) {
            jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("0"));
        } else {
            jobExecution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("1"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The expectation is shell script should call batch jobs and return exit code (0 in case of success and non-zero in case of failure)

This should be the default if you run your app with:

```
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args)));
```

If you want to customize the exit code, you need to define an `ExiteCodeGenerator`. Here is an example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExitCodeApplication {

   @Bean
   public ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator() {
      return () -> 42;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(ExitCodeApplication.class, args)));
   }

}
```

You can find more details in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit).

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud. My Spring boot batch is deployed on the Tomcat container as war and want to make sure application keeps running even after batch is failed. How about defining exit code in the controller? Thinking from the shell script I make http call and get 0/non-zero status upon batch completion.